# Python Irc-Bot EOF from client on socket close and shutdown

Tags: python, sockets, irc, shutdown

i've done an IRC-Bot in Python.
I wanted to create a shutdown command.
It look like this:

```
self.SendMessage("Bye!", self.connectedchannel) # Send bye to the connected channel
self.connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) # Shutdown the socket
self.connection.close() # Close the socket
sys.exit() # Exit the program
```

But in IRC the bot disconnects with "EOF from client", it doesnt disconnect properly.
How to change my code it does?

Comment: you have to send a `QUIT` message, then close the connection. (Not via `PRIVMSG`, I mean something like `QUIT :Bye!`)

Comment: thank you, this worked! could you add this as answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you close the socket, send an `QUIT` message:

```
QUIT :Bye!
```

This should fix it.